# Deadlock on table inventory_pickup_location_quote_address

Tags: database, inventory

Magento 2.4.5-p5 with MariaDB. I regularily get this error:

> SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: `` DELETE FROM `inventory_pickup_location_quote_address` WHERE (address_id = ...) ``

When I check the table `inventory_pickup_location_quote_address`, it’s empty. This seems to be a table from the [InventoryInStorePickupQuote](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/module-reference/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-quote/) module but I’m not sure what it’s used for and why it gets deadlocks. I couldn’t find anything on this on the Web.

What’s this table for, and what could cause deadlocks on it?